# Join new table with SQL query

Tags: mysql, wpdb, join-tables

I created a plugin with a new table (`wp_soundcloud`) and I need to retrieve the data from that new table along with the post data.

Here is my query:

```
 $querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.*, 
    FROM $wpdb->posts 
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->soundcloud ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->soundcloud.idpost)
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'soundcloud'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_name = '$name'
    ";
 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

…and here is debug:

```
  ["last_query"]=>
  string(176) "
    SELECT wp_posts.*, .*
    FROM wp_posts 
    LEFT JOIN  ON(wp_posts.ID = .idpost)
    WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'soundcloud'
    AND wp_posts.post_name = 'test-demo'
    "
```

…and the error:

```
  ["last_error"]=>
  string(226) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_posts 
    LEFT JOIN  ON(wp_posts.ID = .idpost)
    WHERE wp_posts.post_' at line 2"
```

The problem is the `LEFT JOIN  ON(wp_posts.ID = .idpost)`. But why did the query not `JOIN` the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Always escape/prepare your data

Don't leave it open to injections:

```
global $wpdb;
$all_posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
    "
        SELECT %s.*
            FROM %s 
            LEFT JOIN %s ON(%s = %s)
        WHERE %s = 'soundcloud'
        AND %s = '%s'
    "
    ,$wpdb->posts
    ,$wpdb->posts
    ,"{$wpdb->prefix}soundcloud"
    ,$wpdb->posts.ID
    ,"{$wpdb->prefix}soundcloud.idpost"
    ,$wpdb->posts.post_type
    ,$wpdb->posts.post_name
    ,$name
), OBJECT );

echo '<pre>'.var_export( $all_posts, true ).'</pre>';
```

### Use the prefix

`$wpdb;` offers the `$wpdb->prefix`, which would be whatever you set in your `wp-config.php` as table prefix. Then append your table name: `{$wpdb->prefix}{$your_table_name}` or `"{$wpdb->prefix}soundcloud"`.

Comment: yeah! Of course I would take care of the security part thereafter. And thank you for the prefix part, it helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your original problem is that you didn't have the `$wpdb->soundcloud` variable defined.

Your longer term problem is that you have created a separate table in the first place. There is almost never a good reason to create your own table, and given your particular JOIN, you probably should have used the postmeta functions instead.

Comment: I understand, I create a new section on my blog with `register_post_type`
I create this separate table to add new information for each new post... I will also encode a voting system for each post
but how can I do otherwise? add new fields in the table wp_post?

Comment: Postmeta. It's awesome. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta